# NuGet GUI Manager Button Disappears

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

My NuGet GUI button sometimes disappears from the `Tools` menu. Why does this happen, and how can I fix it when it does? I have Visual Studio 2012 and I'm using Windows 8.1 in a VirtualBox-created virtual machine, in case this is a version-specific issue.

[image]

Also, is there another way to get to this window from Visual Studio besides the Tools menu?

Answer (score 0):

The reason I wasn't seeing the option, along with several options, was because I was running the project at that point, as you can see by the orange bar at the bottom.